# What does the [1] do in this python snippet?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested-lists

**b=sorted(list(set(scorelist)))[1]**

I wanted to know what the [1] does in this code.

Full code:

```
marksheet=[]
scorelist=[]
if __name__ == '__main_':

    for _ in range(int(input())):

            name = input()

            score = float(input())

            marksheet+=[[name,score]]

            scorelist+=[score]

    b=sorted(list(set(scorelist)))[1] 

    for a,c in sorted(marksheet):
         if c==b:
                print(a)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ...it's just getting an element from a list.

Comment: The second one, to be specific ;)

Comment: Your program does nothing other than to initialise *marksheet* and *scorelist*. Nothing else will happen

Comment: Thanks a lot, everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it grabs the second item in the sorted scorelist and assigns it to 'b'.

If socrelist is `[97,55,78,88]` then b will equal `78`

This is because 55 will be the "first" item with a place of 0

Since lists run [0, 1, 2, 3, ...]

Comment: I get it noww! silly of me! Thank Youu! :)